# Size of a context-free grammar

Tags: terminology, formal-grammars

Is there a formal definition for a size of a context-free grammar? The only definition I have seen so far is on this [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm#Parsing_non-CNF_context-free_grammars):

> The size of a grammar is the sum of the sizes of its production rules, where the size of a rule is one plus the length of its right-hand side.

So, how does one define the size of a production rule's RHS?

For example, if I define my CFG as:

```
S : A
A : 'a' B | A
B : 'b'
```

What is the size of the production rule A?

Comment: You gave a definition, apply it. Size of A is: 5.

Comment: That would mean the length of a production rule's RHS is the number of symbols? Is there a formal definition for this?

Comment: There are several different definitions for the size of a grammar. The exact definition you use depends on your application. What's your application? (If it's homework, please ask your instructor for the definition that they expect.)

Comment: What do you want to use the size for? That way we can help you find an appropriate definition.

Comment: Actually $A$ is LHS for two rules, one with RHS $aB$ (size 2, so size of the rule is 3) and one with RHS $A$ (RHS size 1, rule: size 2).

Comment: @frafl That's where my 5 came from!

Comment: Hello Naveneetha, not sure this is useful, but people study the size of the smallest context-free grammar that generates exactly one given string $\sigma$? This is a natural question in fields like data compression, Kolmogorov complexity, bio-informatics and pattern identification. In this context, the size of a grammar is deﬁned to be the total number of symbols on the right sides of all rules. See for example the paper [The Smallest Grammar Problem](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~shelat/papers/GrammarIEEE.pdf) by Charikar et al.

Comment: @saadtaame: Sorry, I did not know how you calculated it and you did not state that these are multiple rules.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. I am interested in studying ambiguity for Programming Language (PL) type grammars. The idea is to generate lots of random grammars and check for ambiguity in them. I can randomly pick a set of parameters, say each grammar has X number of rules, with each rule having M alternatives, and each alternative having N symbols but I have no way of knowing whether these grammars resemble PL grammars in terms of size.  What would be ideal is, if these random grammars were in the vicinity of PL grammars in terms of size. Hence the question about formal definition.

Comment: @MartinBerger - Cheers for the link.

Answer (score 3):

What is your intended application.  The article you cited does give a definition of size.  A production rule

T -> R

has size |R|+1, where |R| is the number of symbols in R.  A more precise definition can be found on page 9 of [this document](http://ddi.cs.uni-potsdam.de/InformaticaDidactica/LangeLeiss2009.pdf).

This notion of size is meant to compare different grammars that produce the same language.  In particular, in the article you cited, the notion of size is used to see that under grammar transformations, the size of the grammar can explode.

Comment: Cheers for the link.

Answer (score 0):

In formal language theory, the exact definitions of terms tend to vary.

For instance, context-free grammars as introduced by Chomsky couldn't have empty right-hand sides. They couldn't produce the empty string. Quite a few articles followed this; later on, it became more common to allow this. Usually, the difference is of little or no consequence, but sometimes, it matters.

The same is true for the size of a grammar. In most applications, the exact definition chosen doesn't make much of a difference; in some applications, it does.

This is why articles and textbooks on formal language theory always state their definitions explicitly. So just pick one that suits your needs, preferably one that already appears elsewhere.